# Java recursive methods

Tags: java

Can anyone explain to me how to get the correct answer for this question #10:

[image]

It's a sample question listed on the [AP Board website](http://file:///C:/Users/kcrossett/Downloads/AP_Computer_Science_A_Practice_Test_-_Fall_2014%20(1).pdf) for AP Computer Science

Comment: F) `arr` is uninitialized so `arr.length` will result in a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a binary search. The answers are just weird because technically an index of a sorted array with no duplicates is "the number of elements less than" the value.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer (as per @KevinRaoofi's answer) is A. Your question is, however, different:

> How to get the correct answer for this question?

There are different ways to do this.

For instance, you should be able to recognize binary search in this code. You take the middle element between `low` and `high`. The only "actual" return is `if (arr[mid] == num) return mid;` which returns index of the element which equals `num`. One you realize this, it is easy to see that this is exactly what the whole method is doing.

So you get an index of the element which is equal to `num`. The only answer which mentions *index* is E, but this is clearly a catch. `num` is not necessarily the middle element so E is not correct. Also, if in multi-choice you have N answers of more-or-less one type and one answer which is completely different, this is most probably a catch. :) Answers are usually designed to cost you time.

Now that the only answer with *index* is eliminated, which of A-D is correct? It seems illogical that any of them is correct as they deal with "number of elements", not index. At this point it is easy to dismiss all of the answers as incorrect. But instead, try this on a few examples:

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4; num=2; result=2;
2, 4, 6, 8; num=2; result=0;
3, 5, 7, 9, 11; num=11; result=4;
```

Now checking answers against these results shows that A is right on every occasion. So it must be correct, but why? At this point it should be possible to realize, that index of the element in an array equals the number of elements before this index. And in ascending array these numbers are less than number at the given index (which is `num`). This explains why A is right on every occasion.